# Python counterpart to partial for ignoring an argument

Tags: python, lambda, functools

Is there a "counterpart" in python for `functools.partial`?

Namely what I want to avoid is writing:

```
lambda x, y: f(x)
```

But I would love to preserve the same attributes (keyword-args, nice repr) as I do when I write:

```
from functools import partial
incr = partial(sum, 1)
```

instead of

```
incr = lambda x: sum(1, x)
```

I know that something like this is very easy to write, but I am wondering if there is already a standard way of ignoring arguments.

One common usecase of this would be Qts Signals and Slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a decorator that removes a certain number of arguments from the call:

```
def ignoreargs(func, count):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*(args[count:]), **kwargs)
    return newfunc
```

```
>>> def test(a, b):
        print(a, b)
>>> test3 = ignoreargs(test, 3)
>>> test3(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
4 5
```

> my basic idea would be to make it more generic by default, e.g. having the signature: `remap_args(f, mapping)` where mapping is an iterable of ints which give you the position of the argument of the created function.

```
def remap_args(func, mapping):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        newargs = [args[m] for m in mapping]
        return func(*newargs, **kwargs)
    return newfunc
```

```
>>> t = remap_args(test, [5, 2])
>>> t(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
5 2
```

Comment: My understanding is that the OP wants a function that behaves exactly like `f`, but takes few arguments _more_.

Comment: This is not what I intended to do... I want to convert a function with one argument into a function with two arguments, where one argument is ignored.

Comment: @bereal yes that's exactly what I ment. Also I do understand, that it is very easy to write this by myself, but I would prefer to have a "standard" way.

Comment: @dreuter it doesn't seem easy to make it as generic as `partial`. It's easy to add arguments to a function, but it may be harder to figure out which arguments to ignore in a common case.

Comment: @bereal my basic idea would be to make it more generic, e.g. having the signature: remap_args(f, mapping) where mapping is an iterable of ints which give you the position of the argument of the created function. e.g. flip would be implemented as `lambda f: remap_args(f, (2, 1))`

Comment: @poke I am really sorry, but this answer is not really related to the question I asked... I wanted to know, whether there is already a "standard" way/function to do this (as I mentioned I already knew how I would implement it). Also I would not use wrap, or at least I would exclude the documentation, since might not make sense for the new function... Also I was more interested in a good repr and I am curious about the speed of this wrapper... But I appreciate your effort, so I am going to accept it anyway :)

Comment: I am also not very sure if it would make sense to use it as a decorator (even though I understand, that this kind of higher order function is always a decorator by definition)